# Running a Javascript code in windows for creating barchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I have the code from a website, which generated dynamic barchart .

https://observablehq.com/@johnburnmurdoch/bar-chart-race

I am trying to run it using node.js and command prompt, also rant it with making an HTML, but it does not work for me.

```
bar-chart-race.js:400
export default notebook;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

How can I run it my side on windows CMD.

Comment: I get the error above.

Answer (score 1):

You currently need to run Node.js with the [`--experimental-modules` flag](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) to enable support for ECMAScript modules (`import`/`export`)